# Error with Routes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a problem with Routes in RoR. I create a route with parameters and when I create the link passing an object I have an error.

That's my `routes.rb`

```
get 'products_test/:type_data_type/:id', to: 'products#show', as: :product_front_test
```

And when I create the link:

```
link_to 'Click here', product_front_test_path(product)
```

I have the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :type_data_type=>#<Product id: 19, title: .....
```

Comment: What should be the value of `type_data_type`?

Comment: did you define `resources :products` in routes file ?

Comment: @GokulM it's a string value like 'hotel'

Comment: From where you get the value? Do you have this value in a variable?

Comment: @Vishal yes, I have a `reources :products` under `scope`

Comment: @fcastillo You have already defined route for `products#show` , can you please check your routes path and actions with `rails routes ` ?

Comment: @GokulM I have this value in the `product` object like `product. type_data_type`

Comment: @Vishal, no, I don't have a route for `products#show`, that's my route `resources :products, except: [:show]`

Comment: Okay, than that's fine, please try the below answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the param values `type_data_type` and `id` as argument for the `product_front_test_path` path as below:

```
link_to 'Click here', product_front_test_path(type_data_type: product.type_data_type, id: product.id)
```

Also, make sure this route `product_front_test` is before the `show` action in the `routes.rb` file if you have any.

Comment: Yes, I know that this will works but I want to know why I can't pass my object and must specify all the keys

Comment: Because, rails can't identify which value to use for each fields except `id`.

Comment: Really? I did't know that. I think rails search the values in the model fields. Ok, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set both arguments for this router `type_data_type` and `id`, like this:

`product_front_test_path(product.type_data_type, product)`

Comment: Yes, that works but why can't I set my `product` object like param and I must specify the keys?